# Is global variable can be access across all pages of php within a project. for example global $connection;

Tags: php

I have seen in a Udemy Video. There instructor does not include or require the DB.php but they just called global $connection; in other php file and it works. How this is possible. Please help me.

Comment: A vague description of a video is not a [mcve]. At some point the variable **must** *have been* defined by including something *somehow*. "Please help me" is not a question.

Comment: See [PHP variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). In PHP the reserved keyword global is used to access variables in all the session (files). It's not recommended to use it.

Comment: The only variables that persist between different scripts are session variables. `global` just allows you to access variables inside a function when they're defined outside the function, but it's just within the same script.

Comment: I say _session_ for one call of the main script. In one call global is accessible on all files, it doesn't matter if it is persistent or not over sessions (multiple call). Explanation here : [superglobal](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)